# What is a "finite-state machine" and what are its use cases?

Tags: digital-logic, switches, state-machines

On Wikipedia, a finite state machine is defined as  "any device storing the status of something at a given time." However, I don't see how other components, such as logic gates, flip flops, or switches, are any different. A switch has 2 states, and can store them based on an external input, just like a state machine is supposed to do. Another example is the Tri-state buffer. It has 2 inputs, and the output depends on both of them. Hook it up to a D latch and you get another state machine. And if state machines are so useful, why haven't they replaced computers?

Comment: Wikipedia says no such thing.

Comment: What makes you think computers are not already built out of state machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a design element, Finite State Machines are useful for many things, they are one of the building blocks that computers are made of. (There could be many smaller FSM that comprise various parts of a computer system.) They can be implemented with combinational logic gates together with flip-flops, or implemented in VHDL/Verilog in an FPGA or ASIC, or implemented in software. In one sense, a Finite State Machine is just a more disciplined form of a flowchart.

Remember the FSM starts out as an abstract design tool, don't get lost on the details of one particular hardware implementation. The whole point of an FSM design is to solve a problem in a way that can be implemented on whatever type of hardware (or firmware) is available.

As to "why haven't they replaced computers", you're looking at it backwards: waaay back in the old days when 7400 logic gates roamed the earth and Z80 CPU systems were expensive, the cost-effective way to solve a problem requiring a small FSM would be to build it out of discrete logic like 7400/7474. In today's world of cheap AVR and ARM core microcontrollers, the cost-effective way to solve a problem requiring a small FSM would be to grab an Arduino board and run the FSM logic in firmware (assuming performance is adequate). If a sudden breakthrough in room-temperature superconductors makes quantum computing or Josephson junction based FSM cheaper than an Arduino, then I suppose that's what we'll be using. Would not be difficult to migrate to the new technology. And if things go sideways and we go back to vacuum tubes and galena crystal diodes, we can still build FSM out of those too.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't a switch a state machine? It has 2 states, that are changed based on user input.

Comment: No, a switch is an implementation of a state machine. Subtle distinction.

Answer (score 1):

> On Wikipedia, a finite state machine is defined as "any device storing the status of something at a given time."

That definition appears to come from "Technopedia" which evidently a semi-technical dictionary.  The actual wikipedia has a much better definition:

" A finite-state machine (FSM) or finite-state automaton (FSA, plural: automata), finite automaton, or simply a state machine, is a mathematical model of computation. It is an abstract machine that can be in exactly one of a finite number of states at any given time. "

So it is a model of computation that can have exactly one state at a time.

> However, I don't see how other components, such as logic gates, flip flops, or switches, are any different. A switch has 2 states, and can store them based on an external input, just like a state machine is supposed to do.

A finite state machine is a mathematical model of a class of computational devices.  Devices like switches are within the class of devices that can be modeled by a finite state machine, but they are not the class itself.

> And if state machines are so useful, why haven't they replaced computers?

The class of finite state machines is a subset of the class containing your computer (Turing machines), so your computer can function as a finite state machine, although it is also more powerful than one. You wouldn't want a computer that was only a finite state machine because it would be very limited in the kinds of computation it can do.  For example it would not be able to run most computer programs.

Answer (score 0):

The space they take? Old computers needed large rooms even whole buildings - the performance density is **so** much higher now.

Answer (score 0):

That definition is so vague, it's meaningless.

In practice, a finite state machine has:-

- A set of well-defined set of states it can be in (e.g. "standby", "stopped", "playing", etc.)
- A set of well-defined conditions that make it transition from one state to another (e.g. "if the unit is stopped, and the user presses the play button, then it will transition to playing".)

A state machine can be implemented in logic gates, in software on a microprocessor, or in VHDL on an FPGA.  It could even be done in clockwork on a mechanical automaton.